# How to change the final value of several NetLabel at the same time - Altium Designer 21

Tags: schematics, altium, pins

I need to change the final value of the string in several NetLabel in Altium Designer 21. For example, I need to change RED0_U1 to RED0_U4, RED1_U1 to RED1_U4 and so on. I would like to know if there is a simple way where you can change the value of all similar nets at the same time without having to change one for one.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that with the "SCH LIST" panel (right bottom of your Altium window).

1 - Select all your labels.

[image]

2 - Open SCH List
[image]
3 - Select the column Text

4 - Right click -> Smart Edit

5 - Set your changement

[image]

6 - Enjoy

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you!